# Cannot authenticate GoogleAds request using Service Account

Tags: c#, google-ads-api

I'm using the [official C# library](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-dotnet) for this. I've tried everything I can think of but the stupid thing just will not work. I generated the json file in the Google console and I thought that would be all I needed but no dice, says I'm missing the developer token. So I add the developer token to the config, then it says "Unauthenticated - Request is missing required authentication", tried it with adding clientid and secret as well but it gives the same error.

```
        GoogleAdsConfig config = new GoogleAdsConfig() {
            OAuth2SecretsJsonPath = jsonPath,
            OAuth2RefreshToken = "somesuperlongtoken",
            DeveloperToken = devtoken,
            OAuth2ClientId = clientid,
            OAuth2ClientSecret = clientsecret,
            OAuth2Mode = Google.Ads.Gax.Config.OAuth2Flow.SERVICE_ACCOUNT
        };

        var client = new GoogleAdsClient(config);
        var customerService = client.GetService(Services.V14.CustomerService);       
        string[] customerResourceNames = customerService.ListAccessibleCustomers();
```

The one success I had was that I can request an access token using the json file and I get back a token but I don't see how I'm supposed to set it for the request? Would really appreciate the help, this is so frustrating